# How to SET Android Mock GPS location?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps

### Description

I'm having a issue while trying to use android mock locations, my main goal is to set the android GPS into thinking we are in a different spot, AKA fake GPS.

### Current attempts

I have currently tried two different similar solutions, avaiable in both this websites:

- [Programming Jungle](http://programmingjungle.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/how-to-use-mocking-location-on-android.html)
- [Mobiarch](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/)

Both tutorials are from 2012, I don't know if they are outdated or I'm having a hard time implementing them to work.

### Coding development

First I make sure I have permissions:

1. **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**
2. **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION**
3. **ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION** *

**Note**: 1 and 2 are both checked, if they are not available I ask permission using *requestPermissions* function. The third one is not avaiable to be asked, in fact it can only be added through *AndroidManifest.xml* on debug mode.

I also made sure I have my APP selected in *Settings > Developer options > Allow MOCK locations*.

After all this, I have made this function that I tried calling through OnCreate method or OnClick of a button:

```
public void mockLocation(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );
    String mocLocationProvider = lm.getBestProvider( criteria, true );
    if ( mocLocationProvider == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No location provider found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    lm.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false,
            false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);

    Location loc = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
    Location mockLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider); // a string
    mockLocation.setLatitude(-26.902038);  // double
    mockLocation.setLongitude(-48.671337);
    mockLocation.setAltitude(loc.getAltitude());
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    lm.setTestProviderLocation( mocLocationProvider, mockLocation);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If I compile and test this way I'll receive the *Toast: "No location provider found!"*. But if I change mocLocationProvider to:

```
String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

I get APP crash and in LogCat it says that crashed during this line:

```
lm.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, mockLocation);
```

So I'm currently out of options and don't know how to advance.

Comment: Sometime it stuck, You try to restart your device. I also met this problem when checked status of GPS and it always return false although I turned it on. And debug it noticed Not found gps provider. So restarted device, it gone

Answer (score 4):

you must set 
first:

> allow mock location in setting

second set permissions:

> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
>       ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
>       ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION

third use this method :

*setMock(some_lat,some_lon,some accuracy);*

```
private void setMock(double latitude, double longitude, float accuracy) {
 locMgr.addTestProvider (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            "requiresNetwork" == "",
            "requiresSatellite" == "",
            "requiresCell" == "",
            "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
            "supportsAltitude" == "",
            "supportsSpeed" == "",
            "supportsBearing" == "",
            android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
            android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    newLocation.setAccuracy(accuracy);
    newLocation.setAltitude(0);
    newLocation.setAccuracy(500);
    newLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        newLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    }
    locMgr.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);

    locMgr.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
            null,System.currentTimeMillis());

    locMgr.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, newLocation);}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must set accuracy and ElapsedRealtimeNanos values

```
location.setAccuracy(...);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
}
```

Otherwise it throws IllegalArgumentException.

> @throws IllegalArgumentException if the location is incomplete

**UPDATE**

If you mock Network provider

```
String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

then you will receive mock location through Network provider,

```
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener(){
    ...
    void onLocationChanged(Location location){

    }
};
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, ..., listener);
```

And whenever you invoke setTestProviderLocation method, then onLocationChanged callback will be triggered !

Comment: Well it gave my the last toast meaning its working, your solution fixed the crash! But as I tested it my location haven't changed, would you know what happened?

Comment: I don't understand why this new update was needed, anyway, I have added it and still didn't work, do I have to add something inside onLocationChanged? Also, may I add @Override in it?

Comment: No need to make location request, i just wanted to show you how it's working.  Anyway, when you call setTestProviderLocation method, it mocks the provider which is passed in. Means, if you set String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER; then Network provider will return mock location.

Comment: If you wanna receive mock gps location, you must set String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

Comment: Blackkara, will I be able to see the result of the "mock location" in lets say Google Maps? Is this "fake location" influencing other apps?

Comment: Yes,it influences other applications. When you mock gps or network provider, all other app's will be influenced. BTW, if you wanna set mock location for google maps, then you need set mock [fused location provider](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/androidTest/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivityTest.java)

Comment: On my Android 11 device, it does not throw `IllegalArgumentException`, however because of this answer, I managed to find this error message in logcat: `Location is incomplete because elapsed realtime nanos not set.`

Comment: ..and now I've just noticed this: `then you will receive mock location through Network provider`. Another head slapping moment

Answer (score 2):

from @Blackkara's answer and comments, this is the final code, and
do not forget to set the location mode to device only(GPS)

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );

    String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;//lm.getBestProvider( criteria, true );

    if ( mocLocationProvider == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No location provider found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    lm.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false,
            false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);

    Location loc = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
    Location mockLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider); // a string
    mockLocation.setLatitude(-26.902038);  // double
    mockLocation.setLongitude(-48.671337);
    mockLocation.setAltitude(loc.getAltitude());
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mockLocation.setAccuracy(1);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    }
    lm.setTestProviderLocation( mocLocationProvider, mockLocation);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```