# How to set mock location in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to set the coordinates for mock location. I tried to set the coordinates  and i also set the permissions but my location  didn't changed. So anyone knows how to solve this issue ?
This is my code:

```
LocationManager lm; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {       
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
    });


    setMockLocation(15.387653, 73.872585, 500);
}

private void setMockLocation(double latitude, double longitude, float accuracy) {
    lm.addTestProvider (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        "requiresNetwork" == "",
                        "requiresSatellite" == "",
                        "requiresCell" == "",
                        "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                        "supportsAltitude" == "",
                        "supportsSpeed" == "",
                        "supportsBearing" == "",
                         android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                         android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);      

    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    newLocation.setAccuracy(accuracy);

    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);

    lm.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                             LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                             null,System.currentTimeMillis());    

    lm.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, newLocation);      

}
```

}

Comment: did you select mock location app as your app in developer options?

Comment: yes i selected allow mock location in developers option.

Comment: [I think you might check it out here ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40562194/4883170)